# Increase the time window in Resource Monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, resource-monitor, resource-usage

The Resource Monitor in Windows 10 shows only last 60 seconds (see below). How do I increase it to several minutes? I know that in the Task Manager, I can do View > Update speed > Low, which will give me 4 minutes (well, I'd need longer interval btw). How do I do it in Resource Monitor?

[image]

Comment: Would Performance Monitor give you what you want? You can specify the duration.

Comment: @spikey_richie hmm, definitely, but it seems very complicated. If you showed me how to get there the % of physical memory in use (or in MB) and the % of CPU used I'd consider it an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open up Performance Monitor
2. Click 'Performance Monitor' under Performance > Monitoring Tools
3. Click the green + above the chart window to Add Counters
4. Leave computer as `Local Computer`
5. Scroll down to Memory and click the expand arrow
6. Highlight `% Committed Bytes in Use` and click `Add >>` at the bottom
7. Expand Processor and select `% Processor Time` from the list, and again click `Add >>`
8. Click OK

You'll now see 2 lines drawn from left to right, showing the relevant %'age values.
Right-click a counter from the bottom panel to change its properties (sample rate, duration, colour)

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me which option to chose for increasing the duration of Network graph?

Comment: @Whip You need to ask that as a new question.